# Incomplete reply from server when using buffer bigger than 1 byte

Tags: c#, buffer, tcpclient, tcpsocket

I'm sending a XML-formatted message to server using TCP socket. Server responds with complete message (I've checked with WireShark), but I have a problem with completing it on my side. When I use buffer larger than 1 byte the response lacks the remaining size of buffer in the end of the message. When using 1 byte buffer it works in 99% of cases. I think it has something to do with the `StringBuilder`I'm using, but I'm already out of ideas. I've also tried `NetworkStream` and `StreamSocket`, but without a luck. Any help or response will be appreciated.

```
    public string StartClient(string message, string ip, int port) {

    byte[] bytes = new byte[1];
    int bytesRec = 0;
    StringBuilder reply = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse(ip);
        IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port);

        Socket sender = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            sender.Connect(remoteEP);

            byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);

            sender.Send(msg);

            do
            {
                bytesRec = sender.Receive(bytes);

                if (bytesRec == 0)
                {
                    sender.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                    sender.Close();
                    break;
                }

                else
                {
                    reply.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec));
                }
            } while (sender.Available > 0);
        }

    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        return e.ToString();
    }

    return reply.ToString(); ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the line:

```
while (sender.Available > 0)
```

to:

```
while (bytesRec > 0)
```

Comment: Now application hangs and it looks like the loop is not ending.

Comment: OK - It works for me - but it's not the optimal of ensuring you've read everything from the network. If you control the server you can use the first 4 bytes in the message to specify the total length of the message. Then you'll continue to read until you've read total length.

Comment: I've made some tests and it works as you say when I set `Socket.ReceiveTimeout` to ~1000ms and set buffor to the size of largest packet received, in my case it's 1514 bytes. I guess server is not sending data in time and sometimes `Socket.Receive()` gets '0' in the middle of connection, what causes the loop to end. Anyway, thanks for the idea!